# ThreadLocal in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-local

I have a Spring MVC (v4.1.3) web application with javascript UI. I have implemented a custom DispatcherServlet and configured the same in web.xml

There is a unique screen code which is sent in the HTTP Header of each request made by the UI to server.

In the doService method of my custom dispatcher servlet, I capture the HTTP Header and put the value in a ThreadLocal dto variable. I access this ThreadLocal variable in the service layer for performing some audit logic which is common for all requests.

Code from CustomDispatcherServlet:

```java
protected void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String uiCode = request.getHeader("uiCode");

    if ((uiCode != null && !uiCode.trim().isEmpty())) {
        UiCodeDto uiCodeDto = new UiCodeDto(uiCode);
        final ThreadLocal<UiCodeDto> threadLocalUser = new ThreadLocal<UiCodeDto>();
        threadLocalUser.set(uiCodeDto);
    }

    ...
    super.doService(request, response);
}
```

Code from service layer:

```java
UiCodeDto temp = ThreadLocalUtil.getUiCodeDto(Thread.currentThread());
```

Code of ThreadLocalUtil to retrieve the value from ThreadLocal:

```java
public final class ThreadLocalUtil {
    public static UiCodeDto getUiCodeDto(Thread currThread) {
        UiCodeDto UiCodeDto = null;

        try {
            Field threadLocals = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("threadLocals");
            threadLocals.setAccessible(true);
            Object currentThread = threadLocals.get(currThread);
            Field threadLocalsMap = currentThread.getClass().getDeclaredField("table");
            threadLocalsMap.setAccessible(true);
            threadLocalsMap.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] objectKeys = (Object[]) threadLocalsMap.get(currentThread);
            for (Object objectKey : objectKeys) {
                if (objectKey != null) {
                    Field objectMap = objectKey.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
                    objectMap.setAccessible(true);
                    Object object = objectMap.get(objectKey);

                    if (object instanceof UiCodeDto) {
                        UiCodeDto = (UiCodeDto) object;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }

        return UiCodeDto;
    }
}
```

The problem is as follows - 
1. I am getting random values of screen code - which means the value of some http request N is coming in http request N+1.
2. There are null DTOs in ThreadLocal variable with same name - hence, sometimes when I access the ThreadLocal in service layer, I get a null

I need help in understanding the behavior of ThreadLocal in DispatcherServlet - why would it get values of another request in doService method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the container uses a thread pool to service requests, as you are only settings things and not clearing values. Next to that the way to retrieve values is quite hideous imho. I also don't get why on earth you would need a custom `DispatcherServlet` for this. Use a `Filter` which uses a `UiCodeHolder` (much like the `LocaleResolver` and friends work) to set, retrieve and clear the `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Adding what @M.Deinum said. ThreadLocal should not be used whenever there are Thread Pools being used. It will result in Memory leaks.

Comment: Why do you use threadlocal in doservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is error prone and hard to understand also why would you need a custom `DispatcherServlet`. A filter seems more suited for this task.

```
public class UiCodeFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    protected void doFilterInternally(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        try {
            String uiCode = req.getHeader("uiCode");

            if ((uiCode != null && !uiCode.trim().isEmpty())) {
                UiCodeDto uiCodeDto = new UiCodeDto(uiCode);
                UiCodeHolder.set(uiCodeDta);
            }
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } finally {
            UiCodeHolder.clear(); // Always clear!
        }

    }
}
```

The `UiCodeHolder` has a `static` `ThreadLocal` to keep the value.

```
public abstract class UiCodeHolder {
    static ThreadLocal<UiCodeDto> current = new ThreadLocal<>()

    public void set(UiCodeDto uiCode) {
        current.set(uiCode);
    }

    public UiCodeDta get() {
        return current.get();
    }

    public void clear() {
        current.remove(); // for older versions use current.set(null);
    }
}
```

In your service you can now simply do `UiContextHolder.get()` to obtain the correct value. The `UiCodeFilter` takes care of setting the value and at the end of the request clears the value again to prevent leaking.

This approach doesn't require ugly reflection hooks, is quite easy to understand is is used by Spring, Hibernate and frameworks alike.

Comment: Even the `Holder` is a bit redundant as the `ThreadLocal` can be placed as a static field in the filter directly.

Comment: Well you could, but referencing web related things from a servlet layer is no go in my book. You then have a (in)direct dependency in your service layer to the web, which is not something you want in a properly separated application.

Answer (score 0):

A more Spring way of doing this is to use a [request-scoped bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) to extract and hold the header:

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UiCodeDto {
    private String uiCode;

    @Inject
    public void setCode(HttpServletRequest req) {
        uiCode = req.getHeader("uiCode");
    }

    public String getUiCode() {
        return uiCode;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like a normal bean:

```
@Service
public class RandomService {

    @Inject
    UiCodeDto uiCodeDto;

    public void handle() {
        System.out.println(uiCodeDto.getUiCode());
    }
}
```